# Override `hash` as NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to override hash within a class as an NSNumber instead of a NSUInteger? Such as this:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *hash;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize hash = _hash;
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `hash` is declared by the `NSObject` protocol and is expected to return an `NSUInteger`.

You could do something like this, though:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@private
    NSNumber *_hash;
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [_hash unsignedIntegerValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Is there a way to setHash using an NSNumber? The mapping is trying to set this object's hash using an NSNumber.

Comment: @brdu: `NSObject` doesn't define `setHash:`, so I guess you could implement that method any way you want.

Comment: @mipadi You *could*, but it is generally a very bad idea to change the hash of an instance after its creation.